# GetLastInputInfo() blocks a function

Tags: c++, winapi, event-handling

My main function is a classic windows message loop with a timer:

```
int main()
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;

    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) &MainLoop);
    while((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
   {
     if(bRet == -1)
     {
         return -1;
     }
     else
     {
         TranslateMessage(&msg);
         DispatchMessage(&msg);
     }
   }
   return msg.wParam;
}
```

and here is the main loop:

```
void MainLoop() {
    PLASTINPUTINFO plii = NULL;

    cout << "in main loop" << endl;
    if(GetLastInputInfo(plii) == 0) { exit(-1); };
    cout << "in main loop 2" << endl;
}
```

The second message ("in main loop 2") never displays but the first one displays every second. Is there a reason GetLastInputInfo() does not return?

Comment: It's an out param.  Try 'GetLastInputInfo(&plii)'.

Comment: Oh wait - you need an acutal LASTINPUTINFO struct to point at, not a pointer, so, 'LASTINPUTINFO lli' and 'GetLastInputInfo(&lii)'.

Comment: Cannot compile using &plii, plii is already a pointer on a LASTINPUTINFO (a PLASTINPUTINFO) as required by GetLastInputInfo()

Comment: well a PLASTINPUTINFO is a LASTINPUTINFO pointer ^^ and it doesn't work better using a LASTINPUTINFO plii and a pointer on plii as parameter to GetLastInputInfo()

Comment: Did you set the 'cbSize' value in the struct?  MSDN: 'The size of the structure, in bytes. This member must be set to sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO).'

Comment: Also, you forgot to search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760240/getlastinputinfo-always-0-zero

Comment: yup, forgot to search and to initialize cbSize. Thanks :/

Comment: It's poor taste to delete a question after someone helped you find the answer.

Comment: Oh well my bad, the thread didn't update and I didn't see an answer was posted. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetLastInputInfo() needs to return extended data into a struct.  It cannot return a pointer to the struct because of lifetime and memory-management issues, so you have to provide it.  Since it needs to modify the struct, you have to supply the address of the struct as a parameter, ie:

```
LASTINPUTINFO lli;
..
GetLastInputInfo(&lii);
```

Since later vrsions of this API may wish to return more/extended data, the first element of the struct is a 'UINT  cbSize;' integer that must be set to the size of the struct you provide.  This enables later versions of the APi to return more data when requried while still being backwards-compatible with the earler version, so:

```
LASTINPUTINFO lli;
..
lii.cbSize=sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
GetLastInputInfo(&lii);
```